# Laravel Cashier 7.2 Creating a Subscription

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am in the early steps of implementing Cashier to work with Stripe for the billing of my product.

I am running Laravel 5.7 with Cashier 7.2

I have the following code to create the subscription:

```
$token = $request->stripeToken;
$organisation = Organisation::findOrFail($request->organisationid);
$organisation->newSubscription('Test Name', 'plan')->create($token);
```

When I run this code, I get the `error: Missing required param: source.`

$request->stripeToken is received from the Stripe JS form and does display a result.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I assume you've added the billable trait to the `Organisation` model?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Joe. Yes, have added the Billable trait to the organisation model. I followed all the steps laid out in the docs